# Does the power armor near Murkwater Construction Site spawn as X-01 at high levels?

Tags: fallout-4

I'm playing at level 90+ and am trying to locate spare parts for a set of X-01 power armor.  I have come back to the power armor beside the crashed vertibird near Murkwater Construction Site several times hoping that it would be X-01 but no luck.  The best I've seen so far is T-60.

Does this suit ever spawn X-01 when the player is at higher levels?  Just wondering if I should give up on this location and try elsewhere.

Notes:

1. I do have the Nuka World DLC.
2. I've already obtained the initial X-01 suits from various locations (e.g. Nuka World, Fort Hagen, 35 Court, etc.) and am now looking for *spare parts*.

[image: Power Armor beside Crashed Vertibird]

Answer (score 3):

Most power armor located around the Commonwealth is level scaled. For example, at lower levels one will find T-45 power armor though at higher levels it can range from T-51 power armor up to X-01 power armor. Leveled frames spawn with T-45 pieces at levels 1-13, T-51 pieces at levels 14-20, T-60 pieces at levels 21-27 and X-01 pieces at level 28 and above. The upgrade level of armor pieces also increases within these ranges, e.g. T-45b armor will spawn starting at level 11. The armor pieces generated do not include previous levels, e.g. a leveled frame encountered at level 26 will only have T-60 pieces.

Source: http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Power_armor_(Fallout_4)#Leveled_power_armor

Comment: i'm now at level 115, and have yet to find any X-01 power armor parts.  All the frames I'm finding have had T-60 or lower.

Comment: Probably when the instance of the Power Armor is loaded when approaching it. It locks it's level so even when you return later, the level haven't increased. But you should be able to find a full X-01 power armor somewhere like the Quantum X-01 in Nuka World